# datepicker filter not working properly at the first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to make the filter date from and to in my website page. I am using datepicker jquery. What I want to do is, the user need to select date in "from" and "to" textbox. However, if the user dont want to use it, they can leave it empty.

So I make the input as required,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.startdate, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" ,@placeholder = "Select From Date" , @id="from" , @required = "required" })

 @Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => Model.finishdate, new { @class = "datepicker form-control", @placeholder = "Select To Date" , @id = "to" , @required = "required" })
```

and in javascript, I remove it if the length of the textbox == 0 like in this code below

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
if ($('#to').val().length == 0 && $('#from').val().length == 0) {
                $('#from').removeAttr('required');
                $('#to').removeAttr('required');
            }
  })
```

With this, i can submit the request without fill in the filter date. However, after I select the date in "from" textbox, and leave the "to" textbox as empty, it still can be submitted at first. then I tried to execute again, in "to" textbox says that "this field is required".

So basically, I dont understand why on the first load, it still can be submitted eventhough I leave the "to" textbox as empty. Anyone know what happened? so it seems at the first load, the textbox "from" still detect it as empty, and the javascript still valid.

Comment: Because you are removing required attributes if length for both text box is 0

Comment: What is the initial value for your textboxes?

Comment: When are you telling to your form that It can't be sent if  `#From` is not empty? Because the only thing I see right now is that whatever happens just send it, because `from` and `to` will ALWAYS be empty at start.

Comment: the initial value for from and to is empty.

Comment: I set the attribute for the textbox as required as default.
 `@required = "required"`

Comment: But what I dont understand is, when I select date in "from" textbox, then send it, it can be submitted at first, then in the second try, it can't. 

my question is why at the first time it still can submit? because if the "from" textbox is filled with value, the javascript code should not valid and the submit request should be failed since the default value for textbox is required.